# I want to disable an option in a form depending upon the option I have selected above using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this code, but it is not disabling the option below

[image]

Comment: how do you invoke the `function mark()`? your code should work except for the `string false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `disabled=false` first. It's a boolean, not a string

Also, you should separate your instructions in your first if statement